# Using multiple fragments in each screen in ViewPager

Tags: android

I have been trying the ViewPager from recently supported android 
compatibility v4 package.

In my app, I have multiple screens which I would like to swipe across 
just like what ViewPager does. But in my app, I have multiple 
fragments in EACH single screen. In the ViewPager, the 
FragmentPagerAdapter seems to be for the purpose of using multiple 
screens, each with single fragment.

I am wondering if there is anyway I could use the current support 
package for my current requirement? Or I need to go back to the same 
android launcher src to reference the home screen behavior and design my own custom control.

Comment: Here check this other question




  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9146232/android-viewpager-w-multiple-fragment-classes-each-w-separate-layout-file

Answer (score 2):

PagerAdapters are a generic idea not strictly tied to fragments at all. FragmentPagerAdapter adds the association and rules for how a fragment maps to a page. You could write a similar adapter that presents multiple fragments per page and controls their layout within a container view.

Comment: Thanks. Referring PagerAdapter src via compatibility package and using it directly solved my problem.

Comment: could you post your full solution here ? I'm struggling with that for 2 days now...