# Android ViewPager w/ multiple Fragment classes each w/ separate layout file

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

My app uses the `android.support.v4.view.ViewPager` class. For each page in the ViewPager, I want there to be one Fragment, each with its own layout file. Each Fragment is defined in its own file. I am having a hard time implementing this. To clarify, there is:

1 ViewPager 
4 Fragment Files - FragmentOne.class, FragmentTwo.class, FragmentThree.class, FragmentFour.class
4 XML Layout Files - frag_one.xml, frag_two.xml, frag_three.xml, frag_four.xml

The examples that I have seen only deal with one layout file.

Here is my FragmentActivity where the ViewPager is held:

```
public class Main extends FragmentActivity {
    MyAdapter mAdapter;
    ViewPager mPager;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        mAdapter = new MyAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    }

    public static class MyAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 4;
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return EditorFragment.newInstance(position);
        }
    }

}
```

My main question is: How do I get the adapter, `MyAdapter`, to recognize the four separate Fragment files and smoothly page across them with ViewPager? What kind of modifications should I make to `getItem()`?

Any help is appreciated.

EDIT:

So, I tried what lulumeya suggested and came up with this:

EDIT 2: Yes, those break statements fixed it. It works now. Thanks to everyone who helped! Now I have a nice segregation, thanks.

```
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        Fragment f = new Fragment();

        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            f = FragmentOne.newInstance(position);
                    break;
        case 1:
            f = FragmentTwo.newInstance(position);
                    break;
        case 2:
            f = FragmentThree.newInstance(position);
                    break;
        case 3:
            f = FragmentFour.newInstance(position);
                    break;
        }

        return f;
    }
```

The app lauches, which is always a good sign, but is stuck on layout four. When I page to the right it is also layout four, for all pages. I was sure to change the layout in the inflater for each Fragment. I am still going to work on this. @lulumeya - Is this what you meant?

Comment: You forgot to add `break` after each of your `f = Fragment...` lines.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just return proper Fragment instance in getItem(int position) by position.
use switch~case, It's easy.

Comment: Fragment f = new Fragment();  => Fragment f = null; just declare.

Comment: @lulumeya: but what if any fragment hve more fragment? If fragmentOne have fragmentOneA then ?