# Mixing layout values each other when use same layout for different fragments in ViewPager

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-viewpager

In my Android application there are two fragments called `FragmentA` and `FragmentB`. I added both fragments to a `ViewPager` using a `FragmentAdapter` So when I run the application I'm getting a unexpected layout (both fragment layouts are mixed together). Whenever I tried changing the `currentItem` of `ViewPager` by swiping for each time the layout is mixing each other.

My question: Is there any problem if we use same layout to different fragments in a `ViewPager`?

Comment: please post your layout xml.

Comment: If possible please provide segment of codes that are calling these layouts too.

Comment: @Neoh Is there any problem if we use same layout to different fragments in a ViewPager?

Comment: Can you elaborate more about "mixing each other"? Are they overlapping, or appearing in wrong order?

Comment: I refer you to this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15311126/android-multiple-fragments-with-viewpager-and-abs or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9146232/android-viewpager-w-multiple-fragment-classes-each-w-separate-layout-file if you want to show one layout at a time.

Comment: Consider there is only one textView in my layout. In both fragment the text of the textview is different. But when I change the fragment alternatively. The corresponding text of each text view in both fragment is changing each other.

Comment: @Neoh that links are not use full for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer.
There is no problem if you use `getView()` function of `Fragment` to refer the current root view of a fragment. So that you can get exact views in the `Fragment`. You can use like this(`getView().findViewByid(...);`
But there is a problem if you use activity reference to refer views in the fragment. Because all views in each fragment which is using same layout xml has same id. So if you change the value of a view in a fragment that will reflect in other fragments which are using the same layout in `ViewPager`.
 One more thing, think like this, when the activity created, all the fragments in the `ViewPager` of that activity will also be created and runs in background. So if you change the value of a view, android will return 1st view which is having the same id. Android knows only id of views. So always refer views of fragment using it root view (`getView()`).